# import Cocoa in playground Xcode giving me an error

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift-playground

Completely new to Xcode for iOS development and my syntax is responding an error to certain things like declaring a range

```
  for num in 0..15 { 
       println(num) }
   }
```

This gives me an error. The only difference I saw is that I am importing UIKit instead of Cocoa like all the tutorials.

When I import Cocoa instead I see another error which is this.

```
  Playground execution failed: swift_app.playground:3:8: error: no such module 'Cocoa'
```

All that I changed was:

```
import UIKit
```

to

```
import Cocoa
```

**How do I have a working playground that responds correctly to import Cocoa?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should only import Cocoa if you're working on code for OS X. UIKit is only for iOS so it sounds like you created an iOS playground. If you want to use Cocoa to follow a tutorial create a new playground and select OS X from the menu.

Comment: Just FYI, `AppKit` is Cocoa's equivalent of Cocoa Touch's `UIKit`.

Comment: also, if you create a new cocoa touch class in Xcode (File -> New), it happens that Xcode has selected the template 'Cocoa class' under OS X instead of 'Cocoa Touch Class'. If you create the file, it will therefore contain import Cocoa (for Mac OS X) instead of import UIKit (for iOS)